# Effect of an asymmetric weight distribution on a hack squat machine

Tags: squats, injury, bodyweight-exercises

[image: Hack squat machine]

In a hack squat machine (see figure above), does it matter if I put more washers on one side? May this asymmetry cause an asymmetry of my effort in performing this exercise? For example, if I put 60.6 kg on one side and 0.9 kg on the other side, may this harm my spine, shoulders, or my legs by forcing one side of my body to do more than the other?

Comment: Just curious....why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just inertia. The weight was not symmetrically distributed when I arrived at the machine. Then I have just ignored the asymmetry. Actually, I have just added a small washer in the less heavy side.

Answer (score 2):

Because the rails restrict the sled to a single degree of freedom, I would think not:  loading the machine asymmetrically should not result in any noticeable change in the forces on the user or the effort needed to perform the exercise.  This, of course, assumes that the friction of the sled on the rails is not significantly altered by the asymmetrical loading.

You could perform an experiment fairly easily.  Simply load one side with two or three 45-lb. weights and the other with no weight.  The machine itself is too heavy to tip over for such a small difference, and the total weight is not enough to make the exercise particularly risky or difficult for an adult male of average strength.  You could even enlist the assistance of a friend and perform the experiment blinded:  ask a friend to load the machine symmetrically or asymmetrically, without your knowledge.  See if you can tell the difference.

That said, there may be other reasons to not do this:  for one, very large imbalances might risk premature wear of the machine (so for example, I wouldn't try loading one side with 360 lbs. and zero on the other).  For this reason, it might be frowned upon by gym management.